# How to parse json with arbitrary schema, update/create one field and write it back as json(Scala)

Tags: json, scala, parsing

how do one update/create field in JSON object with *arbitrary* schema and write it back as JSON in Scala?

I tried with `spray-json` with something like that:

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._
val jsonAst = """{"anyfield":"1234", "sought_optional_field":5.0}""".parse
val newValue = jsonAst.asJsObject.fields.getOrElse("sought_optional_field", 1)
val newMap = jsonAst.asJsObject.fields + ("sought_optional_field" -> newValue)
JSONObject(newMap).toJson
```

but it gives weird result: `"{"anyfield"[ : "1234", "sought_optional_field" : ]1}`

Comment: I recommend Argonaut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there :

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

def changeField(json: String) = {
  val jsonAst = JsonParser(json)
  val map = jsonAst.asJsObject.fields
  val sought = map.getOrElse("sought_optional_field", 1.toJson)
  map.updated("sought_optional_field", sought).toJson
}

val jsonA = """{"anyfield":"1234", "sought_optional_field":5.0}"""
val jsonB = """{"anyfield":"1234"}"""

changeField(jsonA)
// spray.json.JsValue = {"anyfield":"1234","sought_optional_field":5.0}
changeField(jsonB)
// spray.json.JsValue = {"anyfield":"1234","sought_optional_field":1}
```

Using Argonaut:

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._

def changeField2(json: String) =
  json.parseOption.map( parsed =>
    parsed.withObject(o => 
      o + ("sought_optional_field", o("sought_optional_field").getOrElse(jNumber(1)))
    )
  )

changeField2(jsonA).map(_.nospaces)
// Option[String] = Some({"anyfield":"1234","sought_optional_field":5})
changeField2(jsonB).map(_.nospaces)
// Option[String] = Some({"anyfield":"1234","sought_optional_field":1})
```